# Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be positive definite. Show that $\left[ \begin{matrix}A&I\\I&A^{-1}\end{matrix}\right]\ge0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Consider the definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix):

> **Definition 1:** A matrix $M\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is said to bre positive semi-definite if $x^TMx \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$.

We use the following property from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) again

> **Fact 1:** A matrix $M$ is positive-definite then $\exists B$ nonsingular such that $M = B^HB$.

Solution:
Write $A = M^TM$, $M$ nonsingular (fact 1). Define $N = (M,M^{-T})$. We have
$$\left[ \begin{matrix} A & I \\ I & A^{-1} \end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix} M^TM & M^TM^{-T} \\ M^{-1}M & M^{-1}M^{-T} \end{matrix} \right] = N^TN \ge 0.$$

I am not sure how it follows that $N^TN \ge 0$. Any explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that in the real setting, $N^T = N^H$, so this is a straightforward application of Fact 1. Are you looking for a proof of Fact 1 (or at least the relevant direction of Fact 1)?

Comment: Technically this is not immediate from Fact 1, but it is closely related: if $N$ is real then $N^T N \geq 0$. This follows from the fact that $x^T N^T N x=\| Nx \|^2$.

Comment: @TheoBendit, no proof needed for fact 1. Just wanted to state it so we understand the first part of the solution.

Comment: @Ian, Ah, Oh that makes since.